# Link on image map doesn't work, rest of image does

Tags: html

I have an image with an Image Map as below. I want to make the mapped part link to a secondary page, but not the rest of the image.

Currently, the non-mapped part of the image links, but the mapped part does not. How can I reverse this behavior?

Additionally, I would like the "hover over" effect of the title attribute, but I can't seem to make it work in any of the used tags

```
 <a href="link_to.html" title="this here links">
        <img src="img.png" usemap="#map"  alt="" title="this is a link">
        <map name="map" id="map" title="this is a link">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="321,65,382,187,337,292,302,304,269,292,361,197,332,163,327,153,318,88,314,73,315,70,319,70" shape="poly">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="286,313,317,329,307,353,292,347,303,332" shape="poly">
        </map>
</a>
```

Comment: Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/#textarea): **The element img with the attribute usemap must not appear as a descendant of the a element.** — HTML doesn't allow you to put a link (i.e. an `<area>`) inside a link (i.e. an `<a>`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I fix this?

Comment: Ok found it thanks